# Importing variables from Text file, variables not incrementing

Tags: input, batch-file, cmd

My goal is to be able to go into a specific folder, run a task, then when that task is completed, move to another folder and repeat.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (z:\desktop\cookieclean\test.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var

echo %var!vidx!%

set /a vidx+=1

echo %var!vidx!%

endlocal
```

That is the code I am working on. I copied the code from somewhere else on the web and tried to get it to do what I wanted. the code above is just me attempting to take the test file, throwing in the 3 lines of text as the variables, then having it increment.

I'm sure it's something super simple, but I've been trying to get this to work for hours, and my rookie-ness is showing.

A pseudo code of what I'm TRYING to do would be

```
Input variables from text

Open folder containing files

Delete files that are older than X days

Move active folder to next folder in directory

Delete files that are older than X days

Loop

End
```

I'm just trying to use the cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

You have your delayed and normal expansion reversed. You want the inner variable expanded before the outer one: `!var%vidx%!`

Your SET /A statement in your loop works, but you do not need to expand the variable. This would work just as well: `SET /A vidx=vidx + 1`, or better yet: `SET /A vidx+=1`

I also believe your logic to show results is incorrect. The code below should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "vidx=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (z:\desktop\cookieclean\test.txt) do (
  set /a vidx+=1
  set "var!vidx!=%%A"
)
set var

set "cnt=vidx"
set "vidx=1"
:loop
if %vidx% leq %cnt% (
  echo !var%vidx%!
  set /a vidx+=1
  goto :loop
)

endlocal
```

Here is a much simpler and more efficient method using FOR /L instead of a GOTO loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "vidx=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (z:\desktop\cookieclean\test.txt) do (
  set /a vidx+=1
  set "var!vidx!=%%A"
)
set var

for /l %%N in (1 1 %vidx%) do echo !var%%N!

endlocal
```